# Mime type for all files (*.*) Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, gnome, mime-types

How to set **ALL** mime types to open with the same program, like this:

```
xdg-mime default someprogram.desktop */*
```

In a single command, in others words.

```
xdg-mime default <my program> <ALL MIME TYPES>
```

Or any solution, wilcard, to set all files open with my program someprogram.desktop

Comment: I will try thanks, i give u my comment if it works :)

Comment: ctrl-alt-delor Sorry, not work "*.*", i already try, and unfortunally all applications continue running with the default programs, not with my program :(

Comment: Oh no, i already test with your method using (\*.\*), but unfortunately not works, why?, maybe because xdg-mime not use wildcard, maybe too because xdg-mime uses not a file extension(\*.\*), xdg-mime uses MIME Type, then if xdg-mime not use the file extension then the xdg-mime will not recognize the method (\*.\*)

Comment: The method \*.\* of course is global, but i don't know if xdg-mime support wildcard(input mime) for associate absolutely **ALL FILES** with a program.

Comment: Thanks, by your comments, if you have another idea i will be so happy to read it.

Comment: I have removed my comment, as they are confusing you (you seem to be reading them the exact opposite of what they mean). I recommend that you also tidy up.

Comment: Let us start again: What is this configuration file? (what name)

Comment: Oh ok, you mean my someprogram.desktop?, Ok if is it, then my someprogram.desktop is my desktop entry to my python application, you can see the source code of my python app here: https://github.com/vudaluzusa/vudaluzusa.github.io/blob/master/app-chooser.py

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: the examples in the question are not lines in a configuration file, but actual commands. `xdg-mime(1)` is a command for accessing/modifying the [freedesktop.org shared MIME database.](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/shared-mime-info-spec/) It is a collection of XML files, and the suggested standard location for it would be `/usr/share/mime`.

Comment: Cross-posted on [ubuntu.se] (with more info there): https://askubuntu.com/q/1130775/507051

Comment: Im building a python app selector using the file extension, not using mime type, that's why i need to redirect all "open file(*.*)"  request to my someprogram.desktop file, and my someprogram.desktop file will redirect the request to my python app selector(app-chooser.py).

Comment: thanks im checking your suggest: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/shared-mime-info-spec/

Comment: No, no, no, no, and no. You are not listening. When I ask a question of clarification, this is a question, not some coded statement of help. I did not “mean” anything about any file.

Comment: now i understand your comments, because i never was imagine file globs exists on my system, i'm checking...

Comment: /usr/share/mime/globs

Answer (score 3):

After a quick peek to `/usr/share/mime/`, it looks like this might do the trick:

```
xdg-mime default <my program> all/allfiles
```

If you want it to accept not just files, but folders too, replace `all/allfiles` with `all/all`.

Comment: In globs file i can add a custom mime like "custom-mime/some-mime:\*.\*"?

Comment: If you edit the globs file, your edit will be overwritten as soon as some update or package installation causes `update-mime-database` to be executed. The right way would be to create an appropriate XML file and let `update-mime-database` copy the information from it to the globs file. See [Freedesktop.org tutorial for adding MIME types.](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/AddingMIMETutor/)

Comment: Success, i already made a xml file named "all_all.xml", Where i have to move this file? into /usr/share/mime/application or in the root directory "/usr/share/mime"?

Comment: At least on my system, there already is a file `/usr/share/mime/all/all.xml`. If you wish to override it, place your modified XML to `/usr/share/mime/packages/Override.xml` as instructed in the tutorial I referred to.

Comment: thanks, i will try both directories... one sec...

Comment: Note that there are two separate things in play: `/usr/share/mime` is the system-wide database of what the various MIME types are, how they can be recognized and what can be done with each of them. It is distinct from the determination of what is the *preferred* tool for any file type, which should be a per-user configurable setting (at `~/.config`) with obviously some system-wide defaults (at `/etc/xdg`). Unfortunately, the freedesktop.org specification for this seems to be unfinished at this time, so the older desktop-environment-specific configuration methods might still apply.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work, the mime type has been registered correctly in "/usr/share/mime/packages", now my program someprogram.desktop linked with the app-chooser.py is visible in the apps selector of nautilus, but when i open any app, the app stuck open with the default application matching the mime, why?, because all files are open using a mime type, not the extension, thanks by your answer.

Comment: When i say \*/\* i'm including All absolutely Any mime type example in wildcard: (\*.\*) means all files, in bash * means all, so i need in mime type be \*/\* for mach absolutly ALL MIMES, text, music, video, scripts, documents, images, completely all.